# Quarkus - MDC - Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, quarkus, mdc

I'm having trouble with configuring MDC for Quarkus and to expose the additional information to Azure Application Insight. When I run the application locally, than the information is shown correctly in my console.

Quarkus version: 2.11.2.Final

application.yml:

```
quarkus:
    log:
        console:
            format: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c{3.}] (%t) [%X] %s%e%n"
```

code example:

```
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

@Inject
Logger log;

@GET
@Path("/hello")
public String sayHello() {
    MDC.put("example", "abc");
    log.info("Say hello...");
    return "Hello";
}
```

The value 'Say hello' is shown in the Azure Application Insights but the value 'abc' not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

All your code is ok but you are missing something here.

According to [documentation format spec](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-format), you have to specify which MDC property you want to log by adding its name.

In your case it would be 'example', see updated `application.yml` :

```
quarkus:
    log:
        console:
            format: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c{3.}] (%t) [%X{example}] %s%e%n"
```

Comment: The change has no effect. Azure Application Insights shows no MDC information in the section 'customDimensions' or any other property for the log statement. Only the text 'Say hello...' is printed.

File system logs of the Azure Function: 2022-08-19T05:44:49.557 [Information] INFO: Say hello...

Comment: If I use 'slf4j' than the MDC property is shown in the 'Log stream' of the Azure Function but not in Azure Application Insights. This is strange...

Comment: I can retrieve the information for Azure Application Insights. It seems that 'slf4j' works but the default logger not.

Comment: It could be a bug on the default logger

Comment: I've registered a bug with Quarkus: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/27415